# Kafka reports LAG/Message Behind and the partition offset never gets reset

Tags: apache-kafka

The kafka topic in qeustion has retention period as 5 minutes, and policy is Delete. Consumer group has auto.offset.reset set to "latest", and ack mode is Manual_Immediate. I stopped the consumer, and produced 10K messages on one of the partition. This action sets the Current Offset to 0 and the End Offset to 10000. It also shows that the partition is behind 10K messages. Then I don't start the consumer for 10 minutes, and let the messages to get deleted. I start the consumer, but the LAG never gets fixed. I have thought of setting up a higher retention timeout such as 24hrs, but still this same problem can occur if consumer does not consume for more than 24hrs. Is there a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 1):

What probably happens is that your consumer has a valid offset (let's assume `4711`) before it is stopped. You then stop it and produce 10k new messages, so your lag is 10k messages. You then let all of those messages get deleted and *then* start the consumer again.

Now there is nothing for the consumer to consume, so the last offset that the consumer read (and commited to have "read successfully") is correctly `4711`. As long as your consumer group has an offset, the setting `auto.offset.reset` will not have any effect, only in cases there your consumer group has no offset or an out-of-bounds one.

Your consumer is now waiting to receive new messages and will have that lag, until you provide a new message. Try producing a new message while the consumer is running - it should receive this as the "next" message, which means the offset from which it last consumed is now `104712` and therefore have a lag of zero.

What I do not understand in your description is following part:

> This action sets the Current Offset to 0 and the End Offset to 10000

This is not expected and not correct, if you have not modified default Kafka behaviour. If you did, this could be the reason you're facing this problem. Your offset should be monotonically increasing with each new event.

Comment: Thank you. That's exactly how I fixed the problem, just produced an empty message. However, after this problem has happened, I don't see the affected partition getting any more message, but the other partitions keep getting messages. 
The 'Current Offset' and 'End Offset' values are something I quoted from the kafka_ui tool output. 
ui/clusters/kafka-cluster/consumer-groups/<consumer group name> shows the topic, expand it and it shows the partitions. But you correct, that when I produce the message, the offset becomes 10001 (in my case the first offset was 0).

Comment: Did that partition ever receive messages regularly? As in "do you have set a key for your events?" and "does your key take enough different values for messages to end up on all partitions?" It seems like a test scenario, so make sure you do not duplicate 10k messages with the same key, they will end up on the same partition if you use the default partitioning strategy.

Comment: This happened in production, and then I reproduced locally. All messages do not share the same the key, instead keys are assigned based on the producer identifier (domain logic of the product). So, not all messages share the same message key, but it is definitely possible for a number of messages, produced by same producer, to share the message key.

Comment: Are you certain the partition in question does receive messages? The partition in which a message lands is determined by the message key, so if the message key depends on producer in your case, you should check if the producer has an issue. Your issue is likely not related to the consumer but rather to the producer, since the main issue seems to be that you do not receive messages, rather than not being able to consume existing messages.